# IE10 "__doPostBack is undefined" solutions do not work

Tags: undefined, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-2.0, internet-explorer-10, dopostback

I have a web server running Windows Server R2 Standard, and am experiencing the issue described in this blog post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

In short, .Net is failing to recognise IE10 and is treating it as a downlevel browser without javascript support - if I understand the issue correctly.

I tried the following popular solutions:

- Installed both hotfixes for .Net 2 and 4.
- Manually updated the browser definition files in the .Net framework config folder and ran aspnet_regbrowsers.exe.
- Put the new browser definition files in the App_Browsers directory.

Finally I upgraded to .Net 4.5 which solved the issue for .Net 4 sites running on the server, however .Net 2 sites are still experiencing the issue.

Because this is a live web server it has a lot of windows updates that have not been installed. I thought maybe there was an update that would address the issue. So I've taken a look at the updates but none of the descriptions seem to address the issue, so I cannot justify installing them and potentially causing more problems.

Does anyone have any other solutions or possible reasons why this issue just won't go away?

Comment: I feel your pain. I applied all of the steps you described also but still no solution. What DID help for me was setting the ScriptMode="Release" parameter for the ScriptManager tag, as I saw that a lot of IE10 errors occured when working with UpdatePanels/Ajax

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I haven't been able to figure out why none of the fixes work. However, I did find a workaround that might work for you: Setting the Page.ClientTarget attribute to "uplevel" overrides .NET's browser capability detection. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have come through many microsoft hot fixes, they were working in local environment, but in the live server there was no result.

Setting up Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel" (preferably in a header or footer page) has really solved the issue. I think this the best solution, as your .net application may not detect any other browser in future. But then we may have to wait and see, if this fix has any side effects.